# Function with getline giving extra output

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, ifstream

So i have this function out of one of my programs, and before it was giving me all of these(-9.25596e+061) and only the first line. But then i put {  ','  } in my getline and got it to print whole file but still got the numbers(which is a memory dump right?)

```
void getMenuFromFile(ifstream& inFile, menuItemType menu[], int menuSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < menuSize; i++) {
        getline(inFile, menu[i].menuType, ',');
        inFile >> menu[i].menuPrice;
        inFile.ignore();
    }
}
```

**Input:**

```
Plain Egg            $1.45
Bacon and Egg        $2.45
Muffin               $0.99
French Toast         $1.99
Fruit Basket         $2.49
Cereal               $0.69
Coffee               $0.50
Tea                  $0.75
```

**Output:**

```
Plain Egg            $1.45
Bacon and Egg        $2.45
Muffin               $0.99
French Toast         $1.99
Fruit Basket         $2.49
Cereal               $0.69
Coffee               $0.50
Tea                  $0.75
-9.25596e+061

-9.25596e+061

-9.25596e+061

-9.25596e+061

-9.25596e+061

-9.25596e+061

-9.25596e+061

-9.25596e+061
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Please provide a MCVE. You're probably not checking the status of the stream properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please explain what you think this does: `getline(inFile, menu[i].menuType, ',');`

Comment: gets the line from inputfile, and as i increments it goes down the file until the 8th element in the text file.

Comment: So if you are getting the whole line, then what does `inFile >> menu[i].menuPrice;` do? From your given sample input, it looks like the item and the price are on the same line.

Comment: What is `menuItemType`?

Comment: I was convinced that getline only picked up strings and not a double. So i went and commented that line out and noticed i still have the same output so that line wasn't doing anything,

Comment: menuItemType is a struct, with a string and int. @5gon12eder

Comment: @ashinKUSHR: You should review the behavior of `getline`. Also, you still haven't posted a MCVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems:

- You are telling `std::getline` to stop at `','` but your input does not contain any.  Hence, it consumes the entire file the first time it is called.  Eventually, you've meant to use a `'$'` instead?
- After that, the attempt to extract the price and all the other lines fails.  You would have noticed if you would check the state of the stream as in

  ```
  if (!inFile) { cerr << "damn it!\n"; }
  ```
- Even if that problems were fixed, you would still fail to store 1.45 and all the other prices in an `int`.  Maybe you wanted a `float` instead?

Your output comes this way:

First, you see the entire contents of the file that went into `menu[0].menuType`.  For all the remaining entries, you get an empty (default constructed) string and random garbage values that happened to be in memory for the prices (as `int`s are not value-initialized).

**Update:** After reviewing your output, I doubt that `menuItemType::menuPrice` is an `int` as you've said in your comment.  Isn't it already a `float` or `double`?  The other problems mentioned above still remain.

Answer (score 0):

```
void showMenu(menuItemType menu[], int menuSize)
{


    for (int i = 0; i < menuSize; i++)
    {
        cout << menu[i].menuType << endl;
        //cout << menu[i].menuPrice << endl;
    }


}
```

Thanks @AndyG, i might of posted up the wrong function but you made me point out were the problem was coming from. To get rid of the extra numbers i commented out the second cout, it wasn't need .

output

```
Plain Egg            $1.45
Bacon and Egg        $2.45
Muffin               $0.99
French Toast         $1.99
Fruit Basket         $2.49
Cereal               $0.69
Coffee               $0.50
Tea                  $0.75
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  You should therefore better edit your question to add this information, rather than make it an answer.  It still doesn't make for an MCVE, though.